# Flutter rich text international

Tags: flutter

I use intl package to internationalize my app, but a problem comes to me.

There is a string for English and Chinese:

- English version: `"has $num"`
- Chinese version: `"有$num个"`

Now I want to add some style to the `$num` part, e.g., set the number to red color.

I thought I need to get the string by locale, process and split the string then convert it to TextSpans by myself.

Is there any easier/cleverer way to do this?

Comment: no you have found the cleverest way

Comment: did you end up finding a less manual way of handling this that doesn't use the flutter_webview package? I was thinking of surrounding the substring-to-be-styled with a special character sequences (similar to regexp) to tell a function how to style the textspan of the text containing the special substring, then I could run that function on any localized string. (using the sequence as keys and styles as values in a map maybe)

Comment: @TristanBennett I use html package to parse some simple tags manually. Here is the implementation: https://gist.github.com/Loong-T/5da59b881ccbab0937678fa0bb2a5f4c. For more features, you can refer to https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets/blob/master/lib/src/html_widget/html_widget.dart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually you can use inline html view from `webview_flutter` (ref https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19030#issuecomment-437534853 )

- English version: `"has <span style='text-color:red'>$num</span>"`
- Chinese version: `"有<span style='text-color:red'>$num</span>个"`

Just have to be careful with string interpolation.

Comment: Yeah, this might be the most convenient way right now. And [fullter_html](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_html) can be helpful. Hope an official solution someday.

Comment: I would be cautious with https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_html . I haven't used it, but from the documents, it seem to support basic HTML tag only, not inline style, and definitely not `style` HTML tag.

Comment: On the different note, what would you envision the official solution be, in terms of API?

Comment: Apologize for late reply. You're right flutter_html don't support style. But webview_flutter seems a little overpowered for me. So I decide to parse simple tags myself, and here is a widget I can refer to.  https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets/blob/master/lib/src/html_widget/html_widget.dart

Comment: The html_widget may be official solution, but it still not work well in my case.